# $\sqrt{\sum_1^\infty(x_k+y_k)^2}\le \sqrt{\sum_1^\infty x_k^2}+\sqrt{\sum_1^\infty y_k^2}$ provided the limits exist.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Using the fact that (for $x_k,y_k\in\mathbb R~\forall~k\in\mathbb N$) $$\sqrt{\sum_1^n(x_k+y_k)^2}\le \sqrt{\sum_1^n x_k^2}+\sqrt{\sum_1^n y_k^2}$$ I need to show that $$\sqrt{\sum_1^\infty(x_k+y_k)^2}\le \sqrt{\sum_1^\infty x_k^2}+\sqrt{\sum_1^\infty y_k^2}$$ provided $\sum_1^\infty(x_k+y_k)^2,~\sum_1^\infty x_k^2,~\sum_1^\infty y_k^2$ exist. Please tell me whether my attempt is correct!**

Let for $n\in\mathbb N,$ $$A_n=\sum_1^n(x_k+y_k)^2,B_n=\sum_1^n x_k^2,~C_n=\sum_1^n y_k^2,\\a_n=\sqrt{\sum_1^n(x_k+y_k)^2},b_n=\sqrt{\sum_1^n x_k^2},~c_n=\sqrt{\sum_1^n y_k^2}$$

Then $\lim a_n=\sqrt{\lim A_n},~\lim b_n=\sqrt{\lim B_n},~\lim c_n=\sqrt{\lim C_n}$ since $\sqrt{}\in \mathcal C[0,\infty).$

$a_n\le b_n+c_n~\forall~n\in\mathbb N.$

Here the sequence $(b_n+c_n)_n$ is convergent since $(b_n)_n,(c_n)_n$ are so and $\lim(b_n+c_n)=\lim b_n+\lim c_n.$

Therefore

$\lim a_n\le \lim b_n+\lim c_n$$\implies\sqrt{\lim A_n}\le \sqrt{\lim B_n}+\sqrt{\lim C_n}\\\implies \sqrt{\sum_1^\infty(x_k+y_k)^2}\le \sqrt{\sum_1^\infty x_k^2}+\sqrt{\sum_1^\infty y_k^2}$

Comment: I think it can be rephrased into saying that a square is always non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $√∈[0,∞)$ you mean is continuous then I think you are ok. Maybe your therefore need a little justification. Do you know from your course that if $u_n \leq v_n$ and both converge then $\lim u_n \leq \lim v_n$ ?

Comment: The answers to both of your questions are "yes".

Comment: Then it seems correct to me. Note that you don't need that $a_n$ converge. Its a non decreasing sequence which is bounded by $\lim b_n + \lim c_n$, and therefore converges.

Answer (score 0):

$x_n \geq 0$  $\forall n$, $\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n\geq 0$ if limit exists. This is what you have used. and that is true. Also $\sqrt x$ is continuous so pushing limit inside is also okay!